# Редакция предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Что лучше поставить в следующем предложении - тире или двоеточие?

Однако серьезно, самые крупные мысли приходят и во время длительной физической монотонной нагрузки, езды на велосипеде, ходьбы на лыжах, восхождения в горы.

Однако серьезно, самые крупные мысли приходят и во время длительной физической монотонной нагрузки: езды на велосипеде, ходьбы на лыжах, восхождения в горы.

Или:

Однако серьезно, самые крупные мысли приходят и во время длительной физической монотонной нагрузки — езды на велосипеде, ходьбы на лыжах, восхождения в горы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше поставить тире:

Однако серьезно, самые крупные мысли приходят и во время длительной физической монотонной нагрузки — езды на велосипеде, ходьбы на лыжах, восхождения в горы.

В этом случае смысловым центром является обобщающее слово "длительной физической монотонной нагрузки", а однородный ряд имеет присоединительное (поясняющее) значение.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае необходимо тире. Так как однородный ряд имеет уточняющий характер.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая неправильно.
Если фразовое ударение на перечислении, то двоеточие; если на приведении примеров, уточнений, предположений и т. п., то тире.